# sacar properties de logs

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, serilog, log

a ver, este es mi problema.

Estoy lidiando con Serilog, para logear cosas en los logs. Este es mi código en program:

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
                    {
                        configuration
                            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .WriteTo.File(@"logs\\identityserver4_log_.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month)
                            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate);
                    });
        }
```

y basicamente logea eventos en el text file especificado de manera automatica, mi problema es que no quiero que se vean ciertos campos y no sé como hacerlo, estoy bastante perida.

Alguna ayudita?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto, dejo la respuesta por si a alguien le vale.

añadí: `.Enrich.With(new RemoveProperties())` a la configuración de serilog. Entonces PropertyMissing es una clase nueva

```
public class RemoveProperties : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent le, ILogEventPropertyFactory lepf)
    {
        le.RemovePropertyIfPresent("myProperty");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En este artículo sugieren el uso de `[NotLogged]` attribute que se encuentra en [Serilog.Extras.Attributed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extras.Attributed) para hacer exactamente eso

https://nblumhardt.com/2014/07/using-attributes-to-control-destructuring-in-serilog/